# Running 64 bit file on 32 bit Ubuntu

Tags: installation, 13.04

I have a 64 bit exe file and would like to run on 32bit Ubuntu OS through VMware because i am not able to install 64 bit Ubuntu on my system.It is showing errors in installation.

1)So is there any technique to run the 64 bit file on 32 bit Ubuntu?

2)If installing Ubuntu 64 bit is the only option, then help me through it's procedue

Answer (score 0):

1) No.

2) You can run only 32-bit applications in 64-bit system and you can not run 64-bit ghost os in 32-bit host.